# Perl - reconcile (on Windows) checksum of file generated on Unix?

Tags: perl

(Please note I saw few threads asking "to find checksum on windows" or similar; however my question is different. I know methods (or modules) to find checksum on windows. I am trying to find the equivalent function in windows which gives the exact checksum as the unix /sr/bin/cksum function. As my requirement is to match or reconcile unix generated checksum with file residing on my windows machine using Perl on windows)

The file is generated by external source (on unix machine) and the flag file with its checksum value is also provided. The external source uses /usr/bin/cksum to geenrate the checksum.
My application is running on Windows (Active Perl). I will first find the checksum of the actual file received (by comparing it with value in flag file) and then proceed. 
So, which is the equivalent function in Windows Perl to find the checksum of the file? (which will give same result as Unix's /usr/bin/cksum)?

I have Digest::MD5 installed on my Windows Perl, and I am aware to find the checksum using this module. However, is this using the same algorithm or method to find the checksum as Unix' cksum?

Let me know if any more information is required?